# How to convert an Object by the type name and pass it as an argument to another method

Tags: c#, reflection, parameter-passing

here is my code:

```
using System.Reflection;
Public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA()
    {
        ClassB classB = new ClassB();
        classB.UsingType = "ClassD";
        ClassB.Do();
    }
}
Public class ClassB
{
    public string UsingType { get; set; }
    public void Do()
    {
        ClassC classC = new ClassC();
        Type type = Type.GetType(UsingType);
        Object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        classC.Do(obj); // Error : cannot convert from 'object' to 'ClassD'
    }
}
public class ClassC
{
    public void Do(ClassD classD) // If I change "ClassD" to "Object" It works!!
    {
        //Do something with classD
    }
}
```

I get this error: "cannot convert from 'object' to 'ClassD'."
If I change "Do" method argument of "ClassC" from "ClassD" to "Object" the error goes away and then I can cast it to "ClassD" and use that parameter. But that's not what I want.
Is there a way to cast "obj" by "UsingType" string to "ClassD" (in "Do" method of "ClassB") and get rid of the compile time error?
In other words: (since "ClassA" knows the type name string and passes it to "ClassB") how can I cast from "Object" to the type that "ClassC" asks for?

Comment: The compiler cn´t know of which runtime-type `obj` actually is. This information exists only when actually *executing* your program. Thus even if you *could* infer a cast by using a runtime-type at least during compile-time all you get was an `object` instead of `ClassA`. This is the price of sing reflection: you lose *any* information on the actual time at compile-time and thus can deal only with `object`.

Comment: My gut tells me your design is flawed. Can you explain what problem you're trying to solve or what your requirements are?

Comment: What I want to do is to instantiate and pass an object to another method by knowing it's type name at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sure that `obj`will be of type `ClassC`, just cast it to the expected type.

```
ClassC obj = (ClassC)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
classC.Do(obj);
```

To further explain what this does: `Object` is a generic type, and has only the properties/methods that are globally available (such as `ToString()`, or `GetHashCode()`.)

Casting it to a class means that the compiler will try to convert it, and return `null` if said conversion fails.

Comment: the problem is that I'm not sure about the type in ClassB. "ClassA" knows the type

Comment: Actually, given the code above, it will throw an exception if the cast fails. The `as` operation would return a null.